# Spring Batch restart from last exception

Tags: spring-batch

I would like to restart a batch after it was terminated
I stop a batch when a particular exception throws :

```
public class IntegrationItemProcessorExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IntegrationItemProcessorExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleException(RepeatContext context, Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
        LOG.error("handleException", throwable);
        if (throwable instanceof CustomResponseException) {
            context.setTerminateOnly();
        }
    }   
}
```

The input is a json I read with a FlatFileItemReader

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<UserDto> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<UserDto> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<MerchantDTO>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("user.json"));
    reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new CustomJsonRecordSeparatorPolicy());
    reader.setLineMapper(new CustomLineMapper());
    return reader;  
}
```

If CustomResponseException is throws by the ItemProcessor, I stop the batch.
After, I would like to restart the batch, but at the same line I stoped it.

What I need to to to have this behavor ??

And my job config :

```
@Bean
public Job importUserJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step s1) {
    return jobs.get("integrationJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(s1)
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<UserDTO, User>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .listener(new IntegrationItemProcessorListener())
            .exceptionHandler(new IntegrationItemProcessorExceptionHandler())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: I suppose step restarts from last commited chunk. Chunk is the minimal unit work. Use a chunk size of 1

Comment: I try it : change chunk to 1, start batch, after a moment it stop because of an exception. Then I restart application (Spring boot) and it read the json file prom the begining